# Scan QR Code only when it is inside the boundries

Tags: android, kotlin, qr-code, google-mlkit

I'm working on a QR code scanner for Android. So far I have implemented the functionality using CameraX and Google ML Kit.

Like many famous QR code scanners, they have a box in preview and the app will only scan the QR when the code is inside the box. Like WhatsApp, GPay, etc.

How can I achieve this functionality?

Comment: Crop the camera image you receive from the camerax api to the size of the "box". Then just process the cropped image with whatever QR code reader you are using. [Bitmap.createBitmap](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap#createBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int)) for example offers cropping.

Comment: Or ignore the returned barcode if it's not inside the box.